# linking qt lib errors

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries

I have a linking problem. I installed Visual Studio 2012, downloaded qt-sourcecode and compiled it for vc 2012 and it is working fine together with the visual studio add-in. Then I downloaded Boost and compiled it.

On a console-application everything works fine with Boost, but if I create a qt-project and want to use Boost there (filesystem libary) , I get a linking error:

```
error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const * .......
error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: static class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)......
fatal error LNK1120: 2 nicht aufgelöste Externe
```

it means "unresolved external symbol" in english..

I used the same including-paths and library-paths, but I can't solve this problem for hours.
Even not if I compile Boost with mingw option

Anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you build Qt with the option '-Zc:wchar_t' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the solution, not it works fine.

It is a little difference but it has wasted hours of searching. Finally this link solved the problem: [link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064147/qtboostvisual-studio-2008?rq=1). It is the link in the first comment. I only have to change 
in visual studio: project properties -> c/c++ -> langauge ->  Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type: yes. 
Then the program will link correctly